# Manual fetching commits using `rails runner` for specific project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I'm completely unfamiliar with ruby on rails, so probably this question is trivial.
In Redmine documentation [HowTo setup automatic refresh of repositories in Redmine on commit](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_setup_automatic_refresh_of_repositories_in_Redmine_on_commit) you can read that you can use

```
/path_to_redmine/redmine/script/rails runner "Repository.fetch_changesets" -e production > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

instead of fetching url

```
curl "http://<redmine url>/sys/fetch_changesets?id=<project identifier>&key=<your service key>"
```

However there is missing info how to pass project id to `rails runner` so I could fetch changesets only for given project identifier (`id=<project identifier>`).

Anyone could help?

Answer (score 0):

Get the API key which is set, via

```
./script/rails runner "puts Setting.sys_api_key" -e production
```

Get a list of project-identifiers like this

```
./script/rails runner 'Project.all.each {|p| puts "#{p}: id->#{p.id} identifier->#{p.identifier}"}' -e production
```